# FIXED SCROLL Function....want it to slide (JQUERY)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So, title is a bit broad. I have this function where on mouse/page scroll (about 88px down the page), the "menu will change to position static so it stays on top of the browser window...

Much like this...sorry, my HTML is in a framework and can't share easily.
http://www.1stwebdesigner.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/06/nagging-menu-with-css3-and-jquery/index.html

However, mine doesn't do anything fancy (not like the demo above does). I want mine ot delay a bit then slide down. Sort of like the demo.

Here's my jQuery function...anyone?

```
var div = $('#wizMenuWrap');
var editor = $('#main_wrapper');
var start = $(div).offset().top;

$(function fixedPackage() {
    $(window).bind("scroll", function () {

        // If the modal is displayed, do nothing
        if ($('.modal').is(':visible'))
            return;

        var p = $(window).scrollTop();
        $(div).css('position', ((p) > start) ? 'fixed' : 'static');
        $(div).css('top', ((p) > start) ? '0px' : '');

        //Adds TOP margin to #main_wrapper (required)
        $(editor).css('position', ((p) > start) ? 'relative' : 'static');
        $(editor).css('top', ((p) > start) ? '88px' : '');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

No one can help you without HTML + CSS. Your JS is fine. Here is more simple example without fadeIn and CSS:

```
$(function() {
    var $scrollingDiv = $(".MyDivClass");   
    var $scrollingDivPos = $scrollingDiv.offset();

    $(window).scroll(function(){
        if($(this).scrollTop() > $scrollingDivPos.top+$scrollingDiv.height() && $scrollingDiv.css('position','relative')){
            $scrollingDiv.css({
                'position': 'fixed',
                'top': '5px',
                'z-index': '10'
            });
        } else if($(this).scrollTop() <= $scrollingDivPos.top && $scrollingDiv.css('position','fixed')){
            $scrollingDiv.css({
                'position': 'relative'
            });
        }
    });
```

});